# Best steps for trouble shooting rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What's the best (simplest) way to walk through MVC and check if everything is set up right?

I get a bit frazzled and I feel like there must be a *really* simple fix to error messages like these:

```
undefined method `invitations_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000105ad5cb8>:0x00000105820b30>
```

After adding small amounts of code to my app things break and I want to trouble shoot them myself.

Thanks for the tips!

**EDIT**

Perhaps troubleshooting the specific issue will lead way to a generalized approach,

- <strike>Link_to is not linking</strike> Used <%= %> instead of <% %>.
- The above error is generated when visting localhost:3000/invitation/new

**view** (in home/index.erb.html)

```
<% if @user.invitation_limit > 0 %>
        <% link_to 'Send Invitations', new_invitation_path %> 
        (<%= @user.invitation_limit %> left)
<% end %>
```

**view** (in invitation/new.erb.html)

```
<%= error_messages_for :invitation %>
<% form_for @invitation do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :recipient_email, "Friend's email address" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :recipient_email %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Invite!" %></p>
<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
class InvitationController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @invitation = Invitation.new
  end

def create
    @invitation = Invitation.new(params[:invitation])
    @invitation.sender = current_user
    if @invitation.save
      if logged_in?
        Mailer.deliver_invitation(@invitation, signup_url(@invitation.token))
        flash[:notice] = "Thank you, invitation sent."
        redirect_to projects_url
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Thank you, we will notify when we are ready."
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

**model**

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  has_one :recipient, :class_name => 'User'

  attr_accessible :recipient_email, :sender_id, :sent_at, :token
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :home, :only => :index
resources :invitation
```

Comment: Shouldn't the resources be plural, e.g., `:invitations`? In any case, `rake routes` is often the first place to start when there's a routing  issue.

Comment: well, my controller's name is singular (is this unconventional?) and `rake routes` looks fine: `invitation_index GET    /invitation(.:format)          invitation#index`
                         and `POST   /invitation(.:format)          invitation#create`

Comment: Resources are normally pluralized, so yes, this would be considered unconventional. See how it's `invitations_path` instead of `invitation_path`? That's because the form helper is trying to build the link for the post, at least that's my first guess.

Comment: For fun, try creating scaffolding in "the Rails way" and look at the artifact names: `rails g scaffold post title:string` or whatever. You can delete the generated files from the command line, or just make a throwaway test app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create request specs for each of your controller actions. Request specs follow the request all the way from the controller to rendering the view, and if there is an error it will show up in the request spec.

This may take time to set up, but will save you lots of time in the future, as you don't have to manually test every page when you want to roll out a new version of your website.